# A general definition for cryptocurrencies

Tags: reference-request, terminology, cryptocurrency

I am trying to find the definitions to several terms related to digital currencies. Unfortunately, I am always ending up on Bitcoin-oriented pages and websites which only take Bitcoin itself into consideration. So far, I managed to understand (actually, *“guess”* would be more appropriate) the following:

1. **Digital currencies** is the generic term for a currency which exists only as a sequence of zeros and ones on a digital support.
2. **Electronic money** is a way to realize a digital currency, it introduces a system where there is a central authority of trust in charge of managing the wallets of users and certifying all the transactions. Cryptography is only used to secure the communications between the users (buyers/sellers) and the central authority.
3. **Cryptocurrency** is another way to implement a digital currency, it defines a way to perform secured transactions and to control the creation of new units with the help of cryptographic schemes and protocols.

Now, lets venture a bit further and try to list the security properties that must (or may) be implemented by a cryptocurrency:

1. **Unfalsifiability**: The creation of new legitimate (or not) cryptocoins must be under strict control of the system.
2. **No double spending**: Once cryptocoins have been spent for a transaction, they must not be reusable by the original owner in another transaction.
3. **Centralized/Distributed**: The transactions using the cryptocurrency is done in centralized/distributed manner.
4. **Anonymity** (*Optional*): A transaction may be anonymous, meaning that the previous owner of a cryptocoin should not be easy to find.
5. **Fraud tracing** (*Optional*): A fraudulent transaction may lead to the unveiling of the original fraudster.

I guess that there might be dozens of optional properties to add… but, lets stop here.

So, my question is: are my definitions valid, or did I forget something (maybe some properties)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I write here a partial answer to my own question (but it is only **partial**, feel free to write an answer of your own).

In the book "*[Introduction to Cryptography with Coding Theory](http://calclab.math.tamu.edu/~rahe/2014a_673_700720/Trappe_2006.pdf)*" (2nd edition), by Wadde Trappe and Lawrence C. Washington, chapter 11, Digital Cash, p.288, we can find the following list of properties coined by T. Okamoto and K. Ohta:

> 1. The cash can be sent securely through computer networks.
> 2. The cash cannot be copied and reused.
> 3. The spender of the cash can remain anonymous. If the coin is spent legitimately, neither of the recipient nor the bank can identify the spender.
> 4. The transaction can be done *offline*, meaning no communication with the central bank is needed during the transaction.
> 5. The cash can be transferred to others.
> 6. A piece of cash can be divided into smaller amounts.

In the article "[*Blind Signatures for Untraceable Payments*](http://www.hit.bme.hu/~buttyan/courses/BMEVIHIM219/2009/Chaum.BlindSigForPayment.1982.PDF)", by David Chaum, the digital cash holds the following properties:

> 1. Inability of third parties to determine payee, time or amount of payments made by an individual.
> 2. Ability of individuals to provide a proof of payment, or to determine the identity of the payee under exceptional circumstances.
> 3. Ability to stop use of payments media reported stolen.

From all theses definitions, the definition I would find the most suitable is the following (I obviously forgot to speak about the security of each transaction):

1. **Security of Transactions**: Transactions between several participants must
   be secured and non-repudiable. It must not be possible to pretend to
   be someone else during or after a transaction or to spend more
   cryptocoins that we really have.
2. **Unfalsifiability**: The creation of new legitimate (or not)
   cryptocoins must be under strict control of the system.
3. **No double spending**: Once cryptocoins have been spent for a
   transaction, they must not be reusable by the original owner in
   another transaction.
4. **Centralized/Distributed** (*Altnerative*): The transactions using
   the cryptocurrency is done in a centralized/distributed manner.

Then, comes **optional properties**:

5. **Anonymity** (*Optional*): A transaction may be anonymous, meaning
   that the previous owner of a cryptocoin should not be easy to find.
6. **Fraud tracing** (*Optional*): A fraudulent transaction may lead
   to the unveiling of the original fraudster.